# Git log how to dispaly origin/HEAD origin/master

Tags: git, git-log

Using git log command i can able to see the history of my local and remotes information.

git log --oneline

- b2a4adc added three file
- 5721d1a Adding files

Now How to view the outputs in below way

git log

- b2a4adc - (HEAD, master) added three file
- 5721d1a Adding files

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate
```

From [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> --decorate[=short|full|no]
>
> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If short is specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/ will not be printed. If full is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. The default option is short.

Comment: @viswa I see you have lots of questions and only accepted 1 answer, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers its very short.